# What's the etymology of 巴士海峽?

Tags: etymology

The wikipedia article on the strait in English (the Bashi Strait) doesn't say.

Answer (score -1):

> The name "Bashi Channel" comes from a kind of sweetcane wine only produced in Batanes. The wine local name in Itbayaten is "Bashi". European sailors had drunk with Bashi during staying in Batanes, and when they passed the channel, wind and current were so strong, just like drinking bashi. So they called the channel Bashi Channel.
>
> Otto's interview with an Ivatan on 2014.05.09
> <sub>[Zhihu](https://www.zhihu.com/question/345968272)</sub>

Comment: Welcome.  I don't mean to be harsh, but I don't encourage copy/pasting random stuff from the Internet as an answer.

Comment: I am sorry about that, I will pay attention next time. Thank you.

Comment: I think this answer is pretty good, it's not simply copied , but seriously translated from Chinese to English.